# Value Iteration exact convergence

Tags: matlab, convergence

I'm running Gauss Seidel value iteration on a weapon-target assignment problem (I can explain this more later if necessary, but i don't think it is).  My VI is converging *exactly* in 2 iterations.  I'm not sure if it is because my problem has ~1/2 absorbing states (i.e. if you expend all the weapons or if you destroy the primary target you no longer transition, nor do you obtain a further reward).  Being VI, I don't think it should be converging exactly (meaning that the inf-norm(V_2 - V_1) = 0).  I've hand-computed a couple of the states and things seem to be working properly, but I can't figure out theoretically why it would happen.  Matlab code posted below.

```
lambda = 0.95;
epsilon = 0.001;
tol = epsilon*(1-lambda)/2*lambda;
MaxDelta = 1000;

%%%%%%% Gauss-Seidel Value iteration %%%%%%%%

%Initialization
VS = zeros(cardS,1);
VS_up = zeros(cardS,2);
argmax = VS;
count = 1;
Vsa_T = cell(cardS,1);

while MaxDelta > tol

for sindex = Sindex
    for aindex = 1:Aindex(sindex)
        Vsa_T{sindex}(aindex) = r{sindex,aindex} + lambda*(Pij{sindex,aindex}'*VS);
    end
    [VS(sindex), argmax(sindex)] = max(Vsa_T{sindex});
end

VS_up(:,2) = VS;
MaxDelta = norm(VS_up(:,1) - VS_up(:,2),inf);
MD(count) = MaxDelta;
VS_up(:,1) = VS_up(:,2);
count=count+1
end
```

Comment: Is your question only about why the code is behaving this way? If so, it would be off-topic here, but could be on-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Well - that's what I'm not sure about.  Theoretically, if this can happen (converging exactly in a couple iterations because of the problem structure), then I would like to know why, but if it's just my code, then I can take it to Stack Overflow.